# How to split the string using R, stingr

Tags: r, regex

I want to split the following format to four columns

```
chr6:g.32218989G>A
chr6:g.32409530G>A
chr6:g.33042880A>G
chr6:g.32590925G>A
chr6:g.31006855T>C
chr6:g.31093587G>A
```

Required format is:

```
    6   32218989    G   A
    6   32409530    G   A
    6   33042880    A   G
    6   32590925    G   A
    6   31006855    T   C
    6   31093587    G   A      `
```

I have tried
    `str_remove(xzx, c("chr", "g."))`
but got stuck. Please note that both numeric columns are of n digits, not necessarily n=1 for col1 or n=8 for col2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to separate one column to multiple column (complex column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984925/how-to-separate-one-column-to-multiple-column-complex-column)

Comment: `strsplit(gsub("chr|g\\.", "", xzx), "[:>]")` works if sample is perfectly representative.

Comment: @r2evans It doesnt seem to separate the character following the numbers. eg. 89G in first line.

Comment: True, imperfect ...

Comment: You request 3 columns in your question but appear to use 4 in your desired out. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R, one approach is to use `gsub` to extract each individual piece you want. Hope this helps!

```
data.frame(col1 = gsub("chr(\\d+).*", "\\1", text),
           col2 = gsub(".*:g\\.(\\d+).*", "\\1", text),
           col3 = gsub(".*([A-Z])>[A-Z]", "\\1", text),
           col4 = gsub(".*>([A-Z])", "\\1", text),
           stringsAsFactors = F)

  col1     col2 col3 col4
1    6 32218989    G    A
2    6 32409530    G    A
3    6 33042880    A    G
4    6 32590925    G    A
5    6 31006855    T    C
6    6 31093587    G    A
```

**Data**:

```
text <- c(
  "chr6:g.32218989G>A",
  "chr6:g.32409530G>A",
  "chr6:g.33042880A>G",
  "chr6:g.32590925G>A",
  "chr6:g.31006855T>C",
  "chr6:g.31093587G>A"
  )
```

Comment: I believe the OP wanted the last two letters separate?

Comment: Perfect! Output as a nice dataframe in R too.
Selecting this as the answer since it provided a df that I can work with.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about R as a language but with regex you can:

```
chr(\d):[a-z]\.(\d{8})([A-Z])>([A-Z])
```

and `$1$2$3$4` will contain what you want.

See https://regex101.com/r/mf0y7e/1

Working in R:

```r
gsub("chr(\\d):[a-z]\\.(\\d{8})([A-Z])>([A-Z])", "\\1:\\2:\\3:\\4", xzx)
# [1] "6:32218989:G:A" "6:32409530:G:A" "6:33042880:A:G" "6:32590925:G:A" "6:31006855:T:C" "6:31093587:G:A"
strsplit(gsub("chr(\\d):[a-z]\\.(\\d{8})([A-Z])>([A-Z])", "\\1:\\2:\\3:\\4", xzx), ":")
# [[1]]
# [1] "6"        "32218989" "G"        "A"       
# [[2]]
# [1] "6"        "32409530" "G"        "A"       
# [[3]]
# [1] "6"        "33042880" "A"        "G"       
# [[4]]
# [1] "6"        "32590925" "G"        "A"       
# [[5]]
# [1] "6"        "31006855" "T"        "C"       
# [[6]]
# [1] "6"        "31093587" "G"        "A"
```

Comment: (R requires double-backslash, so I added them.) Doesn't work in R: `regmatches(x, gregexpr("chr(\\d):[a-z]\\.(\\d{8})([A-Z])>([A-Z])", xzx))`, but it's a good start I suspect.

Comment: @r2evans I figured that OP can figure out their own escape sequences if I simply post the raw regex. Check out my regex101 example.

Comment: I don't doubt that it works in general, but it does not work as-is in R, perhaps there is some other translation needed for `gregexpr`/`regmatches`.

Comment: Got it, it was a `gregexpr` thing. Suggest you put this in your answer: `strsplit(gsub("chr(\\d):[a-z]\\.(\\d{8})([A-Z])>([A-Z])", "\\1:\\2:\\3:\\4", xzx), ":")` (you just *have* to love R's need for backslashes).

Comment: @r2evans Not at all, appreciated actually :)

Comment: @r2evans I re-read OP's post and they ask for three columns but their desired output shows 4 columns. Not quite sure if a clarification from them would alter my regex and/or the piece you added. It looks like you use capture groups though so it would be simple to concatenate `$3$4` into one.

Comment: Sorry about the inconsistency. Yes, 4 columns in output as shown is desired. I also realized that the numeric value could be flexible, so suggest `\\d+` instead of `\d{8}`. I also learned a bit more regex, thanks to the link!